# Do we use the definite article when a noun is already uniquely identified?

Tags: articles, definite-articles

Do I say "Answer question 4" or "Answer the question 4" ?
I'm in doubt about which form to use in a test I'm preparing for my students...

Comment: This isn't about commands, as such, because the same query applies to "He was about to answer [the] question 4" -- it's actually about whether "question 4" is a name or not. I suppose "The Donald" might be referenced in an answer...

Comment: No, you don't need an article when something is numbered.

Comment: ‘Which’ is easy to answer: definitely just the bare noun phrase (no ‘the’). Why? Now, that’s an interesting question.

Answer (score 1):

It is "question 4" or "question number 4", based on 'every time I've ever heard it'. But it's also "the fourth question", which a teacher giving instructions wouldn't typically say unless the questions aren't numbered. (The students might complain, afterwords, about "that fourth question".)